# Node map can be called by key, but not forEach()

Tags: node.js, for-loop, debugging

I have the below code that allows me to log a specific Map() key to the console, but cannot produce any output using a for each:

```
let teamlist = new Map()

//code to populate the map

console.log(teamlist) //Shows entire map and data in console
console.log(teamlist[0]) //Shows one entry from the map
teamlist.forEach(team =>{
    console.log(team) //Shows no console output, not even "undefined"
})
```

I assumed this was going to be an issue due to async, but doesn't make sense as I can call individual keys? Can I not call a forEach() on a map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your situation could happen if you didn't add items to the `Map` properly.

For example, if you did this:

```
let teamlist = new Map();
teamlist[0] = "hello";
```

Then, what you did there was add a `[0]` property to the teamlist object and did not add an entry to the `Map` itself.  Remember, every `Map` object is also a regular Object and can have regular properties that are not part of the `Map` specific data structure.  To add an item to a `Map` object, you must use the `.set()` method like this:

```js
let teamlist = new Map();
teamlist.set("some greeting", "hello");
teamlist.set("another greeting", "goodbye");

teamlist.forEach(team => {
    console.log(team);
});
```

Of course, if you show us the code you're using to actually add items to the Map object, then we can answer more specifically with specific corrections to that code.

> Can I not call a forEach() on a map?

You can, but it only iterates items that are actually in the Map data structure.

> I assumed this was going to be an issue due to async

You don't show us any asynchronous code at all.  If you do have asynchronous code, then we can only comment on its correct use if you show us that actual code.

Comment: You were exactly right. I was using the example from the documentation of what NOT to do, instead of what to actually do ‍♂️.
Always rtfm. Thank you!!